# Multiple button calling same function with different parameters in angularjs - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to call same method in controller on multiple button click with different parameters. If I write different-different javascript code to handle it, works fine. But I want to use the same code for all operation...  Here is html code:

```
Note: "breakfastCalorie" and "lunchCalorie" are available dynamic values.

<div id="breakfast">
   <span> Breakfast - {{breakfastCalorie}} </span> 
   <button id="breakfast_btn" ng-click="suggestMeal(breakfastCalorie)">Breakfast</button>
</div>
<div id="lunch">
   <span> Lunch - {{lunchCalorie}} </span> 
   <button id="lunch_btn" ng-click="suggestMeal(lunchCalorie)">Lunch</button>
</div>
... and so on.
```

And the following function should be called on each button click (or should I write same javascript again).
Here is javascript line of code:

```
$scope.suggestMeal = function () {
   //I want the calorie value to further send it to do some manipulation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create enum for type of eat

```
$scope.EatType = {
         breakfast: 1,
         lunch: 2
};
```

Then call with appropriate type:

```
$scope.suggestMeal = function (eatType, cal) {

}
```

for calling:

```
<button id="lunch_btn" ng-click="suggestMeal(EatType.lunch,lunchCalorie)">Lunch</button>
```